# Unable to make a simple GET request in Scala

Tags: scala, noclassdeffounderror

I simply can't perform a get request in scalaj-http:

```
 Http("https://someUrl.com")
  .option(HttpOptions.connTimeout(6000))
  .option(HttpOptions.readTimeout(15000))
  .asString

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder.append([CII)Lscala/collection/mutable/StringBuilder;
    at scalaj.http.Http$.readOnce$1(Http.scala:163)
    at scalaj.http.Http$.readString(Http.scala:167)
    at scalaj.http.Http$Request$$anonfun$asString$1.apply(Http.scala:128)
    at scalaj.http.Http$Request$$anonfun$asString$1.apply(Http.scala:128)
    at scalaj.http.Http$.tryParse(Http.scala:148)
    at scalaj.http.Http$Request$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Http.scala:85)
    at scalaj.http.Http$Request$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Http.scala:85)
    at scalaj.http.Http$Request.process(Http.scala:99)
    at scalaj.http.Http$Request.apply(Http.scala:85)
    at scalaj.http.Http$Request.asString(Http.scala:128)
    at com.me.method1(API.scala:21)
    at com.me.Application$delayedInit$body.apply(Application.scala:5)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:32)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:71)
    at com.me.Application$.main(Application.scala:3)
    at com.me.Application.main(Application.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

If I add this option

```
Http("https://someUrl.com")
  .option(HttpOptions.connTimeout(6000))
  .option(HttpOptions.readTimeout(15000))
  .option(HttpOptions.allowUnsafeSSL)
  .asString
```

then the error becomes:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/reflect/ClassManifest$
    at scalaj.http.HttpOptions$$anonfun$allowUnsafeSSL$1.apply(Http.scala:30)
    at scalaj.http.HttpOptions$$anonfun$allowUnsafeSSL$1.apply(Http.scala:23)
    at scalaj.http.Http$Request$$anonfun$process$2.apply(Http.scala:95)
    at scalaj.http.Http$Request$$anonfun$process$2.apply(Http.scala:95)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scalaj.http.Http$Request.process(Http.scala:95)
    at scalaj.http.Http$Request.apply(Http.scala:85)
    at scalaj.http.Http$Request.asString(Http.scala:128)
    at com.me.API.getJsessionId(API.scala:21)
    at com.me.Application$delayedInit$body.apply(Application.scala:5)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:32)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:71)
    at com.me.Application$.main(Application.scala:3)
    at com.me.Application.main(Application.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.reflect.ClassManifest$
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 24 more
```

The url is available for sure. In fact, whatever url I use (not even https), it causes an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder.append([CII)Lscala/collection/mutable/StringBuilder;
    at scalaj.http.Http$.readOnce$1(Http.scala:163)
    at scalaj.http.Http$.readString(Http.scala:167)
    at scalaj.http.Http$Request$$anonfun$asString$1.apply(Http.scala:128)
    at scalaj.http.Http$Request$$anonfun$asString$1.apply(Http.scala:128)
    at scalaj.http.Http$.tryParse(Http.scala:148)
    at scalaj.http.Http$Request$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Http.scala:85)
    at scalaj.http.Http$Request$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Http.scala:85)
    at scalaj.http.Http$Request.process(Http.scala:99)
    at scalaj.http.Http$Request.apply(Http.scala:85)
    at scalaj.http.Http$Request.asString(Http.scala:128)
    at com.me.method(API.scala:22)
    at com.me.Application$delayedInit$body.apply(Application.scala:5)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:32)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:71)
```

**build.sbt**

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.2"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalaj" % "scalaj-http_2.8.1" % "0.3.2"
```

P.S. If there is a better http library for Scala, please go ahead and suggest it to me.

Comment: Dispatch is the other popular HTTP library for Scala. http://dispatch.databinder.net/Dispatch.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to use library compiled against scala 2.8.1 (that was shipped more than 3 years ago and quite outdated) whereas you're using scala 2.10. Major scala versions are binary incompatible. The solution is to use proper version of scalaj artifact or downgrade your scala version.

Comment: I took the latest version of this library. How do you know it was compiled against scala 2.8.1?

Comment: It said so in artifact name: `scalaj-http_2.8.1` (see, the number at the end) It is common convention in scala community and tools like sbt produce this names automatically.